# CASE expression with NULL value

Tags: sql, select, case, openedge, progress-db

I'm struggling to understand how to check for a null value in a progress case expression.  I want to see if a column exists and use that, if not use the fallback column.  For example, William in first name would be over written by Bill in fn.special-char.

I've got the following query:

```
SELECT  
"PUB"."NAME"."LAST-NAME" as LastName,
   CASE fn."SPECIAL-CHAR"
     WHEN   is null  THEN "PUB"."NAME"."FIRST-NAME"
     ELSE   fn."SPECIAL-CHAR"
END as FirstName

FROM "PUB"."NAME"  
LEFT OUTER JOIN "PUB"."DAT-DATA" fn on "PUB"."NAME"."NAME-ID" = fn."DAT-SRC-ID" and 11 = fn."FLD-FIELD-ID"
```

When I run the query I get:

> ORBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Syntax error SQL statement at or about "is null then "PUB"."NAME"."FIRST-" (10713)

If I do a select * I see everything. It just doesn't like the null part. I can also change the when is null to when 'bob' and it works.

Is there something different I need to do to use a null value in a progress db query?

Comment: Case expression, not statement...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shorthand variation of the `case` statement (`case expression when value then result ...`) is a shorthand for a series of equality conditions between the expression and the given values. `null`, however, is not a value - it's the lack thereof, and must be evaluated explicitly with the `is` operator, as you tried to do. In order to do this properly, however, you need to use a slightly longer variation of the `case` syntax - `case when condition then result ...`:

```
SELECT  
"PUB"."NAME"."LAST-NAME" as LastName,
   CASE WHEN fn."SPECIAL-CHAR" IS NULL THEN "PUB"."NAME"."FIRST-NAME"
     ELSE   fn."SPECIAL-CHAR"
END as FirstName

FROM "PUB"."NAME"  
LEFT OUTER JOIN "PUB"."DAT-DATA" fn on "PUB"."NAME"."NAME-ID" = fn."DAT-SRC-ID" and 11 = fn."FLD-FIELD-ID"
```

Comment: It's a bit wordy for the use case of substituting NULL values: Coalesce() is more idiomatic for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Progress is not Postgres ;)

Comment: `COALESCE` seems to exists for Progress as well.  And is a lot cleaner - especially when you have more than one value to 'fall through' on null. https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmsrf%2Fcoalesce.html%23

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `CASE` you can use [IFNULL](http://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmsrf/ifnull.html) function in Progress 4GL.

```
SELECT  
"PUB"."NAME"."LAST-NAME" as LastName,
   IFNULL(fn."SPECIAL-CHAR", "PUB"."NAME"."FIRST-NAME") as FirstName

FROM "PUB"."NAME"  
LEFT OUTER JOIN "PUB"."DAT-DATA" fn on "PUB"."NAME"."NAME-ID" = fn."DAT-SRC-ID" and 11 = fn."FLD-FIELD-ID"
```

Comment: IFNULL is not a PostgreSQL SQL function.

Comment: @DavidAldridge It is Progress not PostgreSQL. http://www.progress4gl.com/  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenEdge_Advanced_Business_Language

Comment: IFNULL is an ODBC function supported by the OpenEdge SQL-92 engine -- not a 4gl function or statement.  (There is also an equivalent Progress OpenEdge SQL-92 extension: NVL( <expression>, <value> ) if you are not using ODBC.)

Comment: Thanks @TomBascom `OPENQuery` in SQLServer uses the linked server ODBC connection that might be reason `IFNULL` worked.

Comment: I would use `COALESCE` rather than IFNULL. https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmsrf%2Fcoalesce.html%23